# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using mvc3 c#. And the appsettings from the config manager works fine in the controllers. But I want to use these constants in my jquery.

Is there a way to use the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings in jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this works for you:

```
 var appSetting = '@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"].ToString())'
```

Where `Test` is the key you want to access

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use this in the jQuery file, but indeed it's a good solution to put this in a var into a script tag :)