# How can i embed web.config appsetting value in jquery image path

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building mvc web form, there i am creating dynamic div using jquery.
in div i want to bind image which is coming from db and combine with folder name stored in web.config file

here is my web.config:

```
<add key="logopath" value="http://localhost:10117/images/Logos/"/>
```

Here is my Dynamic HTML

```
  courses += "<img src='@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logopath"].ToString()/"+result[i].filename +"' alt='logo' width='100px' height='100px'>";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306091/configurationmanager-appsettings-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign to a variable to be more clear and use in your courses variable:

```
var logopath= '@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logopath"].ToString())';
courses += "<img src='" + logopath + "/" +result[i].filename +"' alt='logo' width='100px' height='100px'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You issue is with the logopath being in "". Insert an escape character `\`

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[\"logopath\"].ToString()
```

so it will become:

```
courses += "<img src='@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[\"logopath\"].ToString()/"+result[i].filename +"' alt='logo' width='100px' height='100px'>";
```